# Dictionary String Equivalancy Problems

Tags: swift, dictionary, null, path-finding

I am trying to code A* Pathfinding in Swift.

At this point I am encountering a problem in retrieving the G-Costs of my closed list.

This problem is that when I try to search the dictionary for an entry, a nil is returned even though I believe I am entering the right key.

Here is the relevant code (note: Dictionary is in string:Int format as it does not want CGPoints).

```
print("\(closedList["\(currentPos)"])")
print("\(currentPosString)")
print("\(closedList)")
GCost = GCost + (Int)(closedList["\(currentPosString)"]!)
```

CurrentPosString is a String, and CurrentPos is a CGPoint (I have tried both).

Here is the read out from this code (I have omitted lots of code).

nil

4, 4

["4.0, 4.0": 0]

(The last line returns an error due to a nil).

My question is how do I make the 'closedList[currentPosString]' have the right format to successfully access the entry and return 0?

Code to generate closedPosString:

```
closedList["\(currentBest)"] = openList["\(currentBest)"]
        openList["\(currentBest)"] = nil
        openListOrder["\(currentBest)"] = nil
        for i in 0 ..< mapTerrain.numberOfColumns{
            for j in 0 ..< mapTerrain.numberOfRows{
                if currentBest == "\(i), \(j)"{
                    currentPos = CGPoint(x: i, y: j)
                    currentPosString = "\(i), \(j)"
                    closedList["\(currentPos)"] = closedList[currentBest!]
                    print("\(closedList["\(currentPos)"])")
                    print("a") //not printing for some reason
                    foundNextNewPos = true
                }
                if foundNextNewPos == true{
                    break
                }
            }
            if foundNextNewPos == true{
                break
            }
        }
```

Tried a rebuilt with this code, it still broke:

```
currentPosString = currentBest!
currentBest = nil
```

Generation of currentBest:

```
    for key in openList.keys{
            let tester = openList["\(key)"] //find way to not get a nil later
            //print("\(openList["\(currentBest)"]!)") //gives nil
            if key == "\(endPoint)"{
                currentBest = key
                foundEnd = true
                break
            }else if openList["\(currentBest)"] == nil{
                currentBest = key
            }else if tester! < openList["\(currentBest)"]!{
                currentBest = key
            } else if tester == openList["\(currentBest)"]{
                if openListOrder["\(key)"]! > openListOrder["\(currentBest)"]!{
                    currentBest = key
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `currentPosString` has the value "4, 4" while your dictionary uses string keys that are "4.0, 4.0". Clearly those two strings are not equivalent.  How are you generating "currentPosString".

Comment: Use [NSStringFromCGPoint](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624504-nsstringfromcgpoint) to convert a point to string for use as Dictionary key

Comment: I do not have the code with me right now, and will get back to you on Monday (as I think I know what I did but I realized there might be a massive problem with it not picking the right coordinates, but wouldn't cause this error)

Comment: The idea was that I used two loops to iterate through the dictionary to find the openList tile that had the least F cost, and then get back its coordinates through that (as I do not know how to convert a String to a CGPoint directly) and then turn that into a CGPoint through the simple conversion "\(i), \(j)" (which is the format I used on everything else). I will paste in the code on Monday when I have access to it again.

Comment: Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no entry "4, 4", the entry "4.0, 4.0" comes from an earlier line of code that relied on CGFloats to make the key, editing this to use the same format ("Int, Int") made it work.

```
if hexCounter < 3 && openList["\(currentPos.x), \(currentPos.y)"] == nil{
            closedList["\(currentPos.x), \(currentPos.y)"] = 0
        }
```

to

```
if hexCounter < 3 && openList["\(currentPosString)"] == nil{
            closedList["\(currentPosString)"] = 0
        }
```